# Batch File: Abort Shutdown

Tags: batch-file, shutdown, abort

I Made A Batch File That Will Tell Me If I Aborted A Shutdown Successfully Or Not.
If There Was No Shutdown In Progress, It Would Tell Me **"No Shutdown Was Initiated"**. My Code Is all working except i was wondering if there is a way to take out the bit of code that will come up if there is no shutdown initiated in the first place

```
@echo off
Title Abort
Shutdown -a
if Not Errorlevel 1 (
goto Good
) Else ( 
goto Bad
)

:Good
Echo Success!
Pause>Nul
Exit

:Bad
Echo No Shutdown Was initiated.
Pause>Nul
Exit
}
```

This Would Show If I Ran The Code With No Shutdown Initiated And What I Don't Want.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5F2C.png   (Link To My Pic)

Its Not a MAJOR Problem, But It Would Be Helpful.
Thanks, 
   Jake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just suppress the errormessage:

```
shutdown -a 2>nul
```

by the way: you could shorten your code dramatically:

```
@echo off
Title Abort
Shutdown -a 2>nul && echo Shutdown aborted || echo No Shutdown Was initiated.
Pause>Nul
Exit
```

`&&` works as "If previous command was successful then"

`||` works as "if previous command failed then"

Comment: no, not really. One of the two messages (`Shutdown aborted` or `No Shutdown Was initiated.`) just _have_ to be there.

Comment: ＋1 for an all-lowercase answer. not sure if the op gets the hint though.